# How to use imsave to save resized images in python?

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to follow a machine learning code [the code](https://github.com/FelixMohr/Deep-learning-with-Python/blob/master/DCGAN-face-creation.ipynb)
and am unsure of why I receive a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'new_imgs/0.png'` when trying to modify the images. When checking my folders I see the lfw.gz file and the directory with all of the images. Would I need to create a new folder in this case and set that path = to file paths to have the images that are being resized saved? This is the portion of the code that causes the error. Any advice would be great!

```
url = "http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/lfw.tgz"
filename = "lfw.tgz"
directory = "imgs"
new_dir = "new_imgs"
import urllib
import tarfile
import os
import tarfile
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import imread
from scipy.misc import imresize, imsave
import tensorflow as tf
%matplotlib inline


if not os.path.isdir(directory):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        urllib.urlretrieve (url, filename)
    tar = tarfile.open(filename, "r:gz")
    tar.extractall(path=directory)
    tar.close()



filepaths = []
for dir_, _, files in os.walk(directory):
    for fileName in files:
        relDir = os.path.relpath(dir_, directory)
        relFile = os.path.join(relDir, fileName)
        filepaths.append(directory + "/" + relFile)

for i, fp in enumerate(filepaths):
    img = imread(fp) #/ 255.0
    img = imresize(img, (40, 40))
    imsave(new_dir + "/" + str(i) + ".png", img)
```

Comment: Error shows that you try to save `'new_imgs/0.png'`. Did you created folder `new_imgs/` ?  Save will NOT create it. Or maybe use prefix instead of folder - ie. `'new_imgs-0.png'`

Comment: @furas I did not create a folder, but will make one now and test it out!

Comment: Solved the problem! Thank you